# Why does the best fit model (lower AIC) yield higher p values than models with higher AIC?

Tags: p-value, modeling, model-selection, model, selection-bias

Background: I am running a model selection in R that includes 1, 2, and 3-covariate models. Each model aims to determine the effect of environmental covariates in the occupancy of different species in twenty-five locations. The occupancy models were built according tot he "unmakred" package to determine occupancy while accounting for imperfect detection.

Here is an example of my results: when running the single covariate model
`Call: occu(formula = ~Season ~ Season + ndvi, data = my_occu_frame2)` the results (shown below) yield a low P value. After running a model selection by creating a `fitlist` and `modSel` the top model (Lowest AIC) is a 3-covariate model that includes ndvi but the P value is now higher `0.04259`.

I do not understand why this is happening, I was under the impression that the top model should yield yield a low P value.

Thanks

```
occu(formula = ~Season ~ Season + ndvi + Imp_surf + Popdens, 
    data = my_occu_frame2)

Occupancy:
            Estimate    SE      z P(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -1.778 0.663 -2.682 0.00732
Season18_2     0.299 0.881  0.339 0.73430
Season18_3    -0.724 1.005 -0.721 0.47102
Season18_4     1.732 0.805  2.151 0.03149
Season19_1     1.650 0.800  2.062 0.03918
Season19_2     1.181 0.798  1.481 0.13856
Season19_3     1.902 0.806  2.360 0.01826
Season19_4     1.573 0.793  1.982 0.04747
Season20_1     1.784 0.797  2.239 0.02512
Season20_2     1.861 0.813  2.290 0.02200
ndvi           1.633 0.805  2.028 0.04259
Imp_surf       1.397 0.891  1.568 0.11682
Popdens       -0.713 0.275 -2.595 0.00946

Detection:
            Estimate    SE      z  P(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.0307 0.248  0.124 0.901388
Season18_2   -1.1332 0.326 -3.474 0.000513
Season18_3   -1.2318 0.395 -3.116 0.001833
Season18_4   -0.6175 0.274 -2.254 0.024173
Season19_1   -0.3879 0.272 -1.424 0.154358
Season19_2   -0.5523 0.279 -1.979 0.047826
Season19_3   -0.6107 0.275 -2.222 0.026270
Season19_4   -0.2314 0.274 -0.845 0.398243
Season20_1    0.0893 0.271  0.330 0.741468
Season20_2   -0.2789 0.272 -1.025 0.305585

AIC: 3535.478
```

Comment: What p-value do you mean by "the" p-value? The output doesn't show the one for the whole model. I don't understand either why you call the first model "single covariate model"; I see more than one for sure. Also generally model selection invalidates p-values (I know that this is not what you have asked, but it should be useful to know anyway).

Comment: I have updated the display to show the entirety of the summary for model with the lowest AIC value. As I understand it, since seasonal change is a covariate, we receive a P value for each season. Could the invalidation of p-values be the reason why the summary of the model only shows an "overall" AIC value?

Comment: Confusing. It seems you talk about the p-value of ndvi, now your output shows 0.04259 but your description says that this is "higher" than the shown one, but there is no lower one anymore (as you have apparently deleted the earlier output).  It is hard to say anything as long as not all relevant information is visible, clearly described, and consistent with your description.

Comment: The top model chosen using AIC in no way guarantees low P-values.  AIC "ranks" models and as such is a relative measure (very useful but relative).  The top model could be the best of a bunch of horrible models or it could be the best of a set of very good models.  (If your question is about "why does this occur?", this is the right place.  If your question is "Is the occu function correct?", then asking that at https://groups.google.com/g/unmarked would be better.)